# Can you initialize a variable inside the parameters of __init__()?

Tags: python

I was just wondering whether I'm able to initialize a variable inside the parameter of **init**()?

This is my code:

```
def __init__ (self, position = 0, memory = 0) :
        self.position = position
        self.memory = memory
```

So the question really is, is it possible to do `position = 0` inside the **init**() function.

Comment: Did you run the code? Did it work?

Comment: #1. Please don't ask questions about code you didn't test. #2. `__init__` is no different than any other method.

Comment: Yeh sorry, I'm new to python. Been a few weeks since I started learning it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but then you'll be overwriting any value of `position` passed as an argument. The default-value is only used if no argument is given.

You can *check* if the argument has a value that indicates some other value should be used instead (this is typically done with `None`, usually when you want the default to be a fresh instance of a mutable value).

```
def __init__(self, position=None, memory=0):
    if position is None:
        position = 0
    self.position = position
    self.memory = memory
```